# Ordering in Django Admin based on a custom callable in list display

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a custom callable in my list display. I want to be able to sort by it, but it does not correspond to a single field, so I **cannot use `admin_order_field`** on its own.

I would like to be able to alter the ordering of the queryset to reflect this, if it is selected as a field. However, it looks like the `ChangeList` view calls `get_ordering` *after* running it via the model admin's `get_ordering` call, and then loops through the given sorted fields (in the format `a.b.c.etc.y.z` where a, b, c, etc. are all integers corresponding to one or more fields in the display list.

In this example, I have a order page where the customer can be a company/organization *or* a person. I want to be able to sort it so that all orders by people are listed first, followed by organizations, and all in alphabetical order.

Let's use this model admin setup as an example:

```
class OrderAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('pk', 'date_ordered', 'customer')

    def customer(self, obj):
        return obj.organization or "%s %s" % (obj.first_name, obj.last_name)
```

At the moment, I can't sort because a sort field is only made available if the callable has a `admin_order_field` attached:

```
    def customer(self, obj):
        return obj.organization or "%s %s" % (obj.first_name, obj.last_name)
    customer.admin_order_field = 'customer'
```

The thing is, ideally I would like to be able to intercept the default code and say, "if one of the fields is 'customer', remove that field from the list and instead sort it using `["organization", "last_name", "first_name"]`". But as far as I can tell there is no way to do this.

I suspect `extra(select={'customer':...})` would work, **except** that I'm using `django-pyodbc` as this is a SQL Server database, and the generated SQL simply does not work and throws an error:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT 

                ( COALESCE(organization, firstname + ' ' + lastname) ) AS [customer], 
                ..., 
               ( Row_number() 
                   OVER ( 
                     ORDER BY [customer] ASC, [orders].[date_created] DESC, 
                   [orders].[order_id] ASC 
                   ) )                                                    AS 
               [rn] 
        FROM   [orders]) AS X 
WHERE  X.rn BETWEEN 1 AND 100
```

The error being:

> Invalid column name 'customer'.

Short of rewriting django-pyodbc, using `.extra` is not a solution.

So I'm wondering if there is anything else I can do, or if I just have to give up on using customer name on its own as a sorting field, and replace it with separate organization, last name, and first name columns.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that admin_order_field is a field from SQL result set. So, what you need to do is override get_queryset in admin so you have a "field" that works for your sort.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset

You will probably need Q() and F() functions as well. I do not know if they work in pyodbc.

Now, this "customer" field should really be just for sorting. It is accessible via obj.customer.

Then you need a function (it could be called "customer" as well) that sorts on that field. And in it you do the logic you wanted to do with COALESCE.

Comment: Yeah, as noted in my question, unfortunately just using `.extra` in `get_queryset` will not work. As far as I know there was never a resolution to this problem. I imagine creating a wrapper for the `ModelAdmin` class that allows `admin_order_field` to be an iterable as well as a single field name might do the trick.